# How to rename photos using information from csv file

Tags: bash, csv, unix, rename, move

I am new to unix and could really use your help.

I want to rename a lot of photographs so they correspond with codes of items that are on the picture. I have a .csv file that has the original .jpg name and then the codes I want the photos to be renamed to, following in consecutive columns. For example:

> IMG_1234.JPG,AB001,AB003,AB004
>   IMG_1345.JPG,AB011,AB012,AB013,AB014,AB015
>   IMG_1456.JPG,AB112
>   IMG_1678.JPG,AB125,AB126

So I want IMG_1234.JPG copied 3 times and renamed to AB001, AB003, and AB004 etc.

I know I need a script and that I can copy and rename files, but I can't figure out how to make a script run through the csv file and copy & rename the .jpg to the names following until an empty cell and then move on to the next row and copy & rename that .jpg etc etc.

I hope my question is clear and I apologize for my limited knowledge.
Thanks in advance!

edit: The image names have directories (with spaces) in front of them as the photographs are in different folders. For example:

> ./Photos sorted/Samples1-100/IMG_1134.JPG

Comment: Are your files named IMG_1234 or IMG_1234.jpg?

Comment: They are named .jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want. The filename of the csv file is given as parameter to the script. You might adjust the paths inside the copy command, currently everything must be in the same directory. If you are using this on a mac or linux, you can also use "ln -s" instead if "cp" to create a symbolic link to the original file to save disk space.

```
    CSVFILE=$1

    cat $CSVFILE |\
    while read LINE; do
        SPLIT=`echo $LINE | tr "," " "`
        FIRST=0
        for NAME in $SPLIT; do
            if [ $FIRST -eq 0 ]; then
                SRCNAME=$NAME
            else
                DSTNAME=$NAME
                cp ${SRCNAME}.jpg ${DSTNAME}.jpg
            fi
            ((FIRST++))
        done
    done
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your script seems to work, eventhough my pictures are actually named IMG_1234.JPG. I was just wondering if you could help me with one more thing. The first column in my csv file actually has directories included (see edit of my question) and I can't get it to work with the spacing in the directory names. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Never mind actually; I will replace all the spaces with _ and that should work